# Should wrong answers be edited or replaced?

Tags: discussion

I've given a wrong answer to a question and I'm not too sure how to correct it. Should I:

1. Acknowledge the correctness of the comments and completely re-edit it?
2. Delete it and give a new correct answer?
3. Add another answer, acknowledging the incorrecness of my existing one?

Answer (score 8):

I don't see any point is leaving an answer you know to be wrong.

Delete it or edit it to be correct. If you want to leave a visible trail f bread crumbs to explain the comments that is OK, but you don't have to...there is always the edit history.